# Convert 1562008049.727648 to 156200 using Python

Tags: python

How do I convert 1562008049.727648 to 156200 using Python?

1562008049.727648 is a timestamp given to me by a third party so I need to convert whatever number give to me to only the first 6 numbers. This will eventually be compared to time.time().

I suppose I could first convert this to a string then do `print my_string[0:100]`. But is there an easier way?

Comment: Subtract 0.727648 and divide by ten thousand. You can also do that using a single subtraction or division, it all depends how you like it.

Answer (score 0):

convert the number to a string and slice it:

```
s = str(1562008049.727648)
print(s[:6])
```

> 156200

Answer (score 0):

Shift the numbers you don't want past the decimal point, and then find the integer value

```
>>> n = 1562008049.727648
>>> res = int(n * (10 ** -4))
>>> res
156200
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = 1562008049.727648
import math
math.ceil(d / 10000)
```

Output:

```
156200
```

Rounding the number to the closest thousand and dividing by 1000 will do the trick.